# Prevent LongListSelector to change position when inserting items

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-phone

I've bound a `LongListSelector` (via XAML) to an `ObservableCollection` (from my ViewModel). This collection holds news articles (or exactly the headers of them). When a new one is loaded it gets added by `this.Articles.Insert(0, newArticle)` since the newest article should always be on the top of the list.

*Now my problem occurs:* 
When a new article is inserted in `ObservableCollection` the `LongListSelector` scroll position jumps to the top of the list. But since I load the articles in the background and the user may already read article headlines something a little further down when the new article is loaded he may get interrupted since the list jumps up to the top of it.

How can I prevent this behavior?

**EDIT:**

I don't believe positing the code is necessary, but since somebody could say "it should work, you just have done it the wrong way": Here is the code I used to add the elements:

```
    // inside my ViewModel
    // this.Article is ObserveableCollection

    private void NewArticlesAvailable(Repository repository, IEnumerable<Article> newArticles)
    {
        foreach (var article in newArticles.OrderBy(a => a.Date))
        {
            this.Articles.Insert(0, article);
        }
    }
```

An this is the XAML code I use for the `LongListSelector`:

```
            <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding From}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you have set binding to your observableCollection? If you set Binding to the list in xaml, and then insert items to observablecollection in c#, the longlistselector should not jump to the top. Are you sure that you never set longListSelector itemsSource in c#? If you set itemSource in c#, then whole list will be generated again, and it will jump to the top.

Of course if there is only few news in list, and all of them fits to the screen, then there is that jumping happening. Then I recommend you to load few news before showing them in the screen.

Comment: This would have been my first thought too, but I didn't. And there are already a lot of articles (50+) loaded at the beginning. (Loaded from the cache, the asynchronus loading is done for fetching the new articles.)

Comment: This is weird, because I tested also this with little program, and I was able to insert items without any jumping effects. I cannot see any mistakes in your code, so I suppose that even our longListSelectors are working differently, or the mistake is somewhere else.